# How to properly rebase in SourceTree?

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree 1.6.4.0 on Windows 7.

Let's say the following is my starting point:

[image]

```
 C <- master
/
- A - B <- topic
```

I want to rebase **topic** onto **master**.
My goal is to have:

```
  C - A - B
  ^       ^
master  topic
```

but I end up with:

[image]

I can then do

```
git push origin topic -f
```

and I get the intended result, but what is the proper way to do this in SourceTree?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Update: SourceTree 1.9.1

You can enable force push in Tools/Options/Git/Enable Force Push. After it is enabled you can check "Force Push" check box in the "Push" dialog.

## Original answer

You have to do a force push, because topic branch is already published and you are rewriting history. Commits A and B from origin/topic are removed if you rebase.

You should make a merge if you don't want to do a force push, specially if you have a team members already working on topic.

You can't do a force push with SourceTree for Windows yet (see [answers at atlassian forums](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54469/how-do-i-perform-a-forced-push-push-f-from-sourcetree)).
You can vote for this feature here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-338

Comment: I'm the only one working on this project, using the well-described rebase-then-merge workflow. Is there an option in SourceTree to enable force push via GUI? Kind of defeats the purpose of the program if I still have to use the command-line.

Comment: @user3858446 Unfortunately there isn't such an option in SourceTree. See [answers at atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54469/how-do-i-perform-a-forced-push-push-f-from-sourcetree). You can vote for this feature here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-338

Comment: Whilst it doesn't have the option, you can create a Custom Action which calls a batch file. That's what I've got set up, and it feels pretty integrated. You can right click on the commit list, and choose it from the Custom Actions sub menu.

Answer (score 14):

## UPDATE: SourceTree Version 2.6.3 (134) (for Mac)

Go to `SourceTree/Preferences/Advanced` and click the 'Allow force push' checkbox at the top of the 'Advanced' dialog.

This allows for the ability to click Force Push in the push dialog whilst pushing a commit.

**Previous versions** had this at `SourceTree/Preferences/General` toward the bottom of the 'General' dialog.

Comment: presumably you are refering to mac?

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE: SourceTree Version 2.4.8.0 (Windows 10)

Go to `SourceTree --> Tools --> Options` select `Git` and check `Enable Force Push` (see screenshot)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Force push is the solution.
I enabled the option in Advanced settings in SourceTree and then the Push work to rebase the remote branch.

Comment: This answer has already been given. Several times.